# How can I create a reusable function that will setState for a variable object property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, setstate

I have an onChange function to update the state on all of my form inputs. The state I'm trying to update here is nested in an array as an object, but I am unsure how I can make a reusable function that will update the specific object property depending on which form input is changed.

Here's my function:

```
onChangeHandler = (e, index) => {
  let currentStateObject = [...this.state.fundGroups]; //copying the current state

  // This works, but I don't want allocationName to be hardcoded. 
  // How can I pass in a variable that relates to the specific property 
  // based on which input field is changed?
  currentStateObject[index].allocationName = e.target.value; 
  this.setState({
    currentStateObject
  });
}
```

Here is what I have attempted but it does not work and breaks my code with an invalid token message:

```
currentStateObject[index].[e.target.name] = e.target.
```

I attempted this because in my input field, I added `name="allocationName"`

Does anyone know if I'm close to solving this? I'm very new to React. Thank you.

Comment: Why are there close votes on this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some example of state manipilation

```
state = {
    random: [],
    counter: 1
  }


  stateHandler = (e)=>{
    let oldrandom = [...this.state.random]
    oldrandom[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({random:oldrandom })
  }




manipulate state with a functional approach

 stateHandler = ()=>{
        this.setState((state,props)=>{
          counter: state.counter+props.increment
       })
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

you almost got it. simply remove the `.` between `[index]` and `[e.target.name]` like:

```
currentStateObject[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
```

Comment: I'm going to hit myself in the head over a keyboard. Thank you so much. I will try this.

Comment: Another change in the OP's current code to make it work correctly is to do `this.setState( { fundGroups: currentStateObject } )`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply:

```
onChangeHandler(event) {
   this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
}
```

Comment: that usually works, but as I can see in his code he is additionally using an `index` to work with. :)

Comment: That does not make sense tbh :)

Comment: This code does not specify which item in the array I am editing.

Comment: It is actually, you can try out this piece of code.